# Generate .1 files from MetaUML .mp files automatically with latexmk

Tags: package-writing, latexmk, shell-escape, metauml

I'm currently creating a personal `LaTeX` package and base .tex document that I can use to typeset my Computer Science reports at my university. One of the features I would like to have is to make `UML` diagrams in `MetaUML`.

I would like to to generate the .1 files from the .mp files every time I run latexmk instead of doing it manually. Beneath I have made a minimal example of the directory structure I am using.

Is it be possible to use latexmk to run mpost on the mp files in the images directory automatically or on demand? Or would I have to use an external makefile/script?

My directory structure looks like this:

```
|-mainDocument.tex
|-createPDF.sh
|
|\styles
| |-myStyle.sty
| 
|\images
| |-strategyPattern.mp
| 
|\output
| |-generated PDF and fls file
| 
|\tmp
| |-generated aux etc.
```

This is the content of myStyle.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{myStyle}[2014/02/27]

\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
```

this is the content of mainDocument.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\RequirePackage{./styles/myStyle}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.1}{mps}{*}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/strategyPattern.1}
      \caption{A picture of a uml.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

strategyPattern.mp contains the content of [this link](http://profs.info.uaic.ro/~ogh/lop/Strategy2.mp)
and createPDF.sh is a wrapper around `latexmk -pdf -shell-escape -auxdir=tmp -output-directory=output mainDocument.tex`

## Update

After @Thruston comment I have been digging through the `latexmk` repository and found this file http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/mpost_latexmkrc.

I have added this to my `latexmkrc` file, however it never seems to run the subroutine.

## Update 2

`strategyPattern.1` gets generated when I put `strategyPattern.mp` in the root directory, however it gives a error during the first pass of `latexmk`, the second pass is succesfull.

I'm closing in on the problem, but my `LaTeX` and `Perl` skills are not sufficient enough to get it working with the `strategyPattern.mp` file in `/images`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Did you look at the [Latexmk documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/)?  It includes some examples for running metapost.

Comment: @ChristianH. Thank you, I shall read the starter guide

@Thruston I did grepped through the documentation with `mpost` and `metapost` as the word to search, but I was not able to find any reference to them.

Comment: There's actually a bug in the `latexmk` documentation in the file `mpost_latexmkrc`.  I've put a corrected version at [mpost_latexmkrc](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/latexmk/mpost_latexmkrc).  It'll appear in the next release of `latexmk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the updated `mpost_latexmkrc` file I am able to get it to work. The other thing that had to be done was refer to my `.mk` files by path. This means I had to use `images/strategyPattern.1` instead of just `strategyPattern.1`. I have updated the question to reflect this change.

### Updated file

Here's the non-comment part of the updated `mpost_latexmkrc` file:

```
add_cus_dep( 'mp', '1', 0, 'mpost' );
sub mpost {
    my $file = $_[0];
    my ($name, $path) =  fileparse( $file );
    my $return = system "mpost \"$file\"";
    # Fix the problem that mpost puts its output and log files
    # in the current directory, not in the auxiliary directory
    # (which is often the same as the output directory):
    move "$name.1", $path;
    move "$name.log", $aux_dir;
    return $return;
}
```